# Getting error trying to run AVD in Qt Quick project

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-virtual-device

So Im trying to run an Android Virtual Device to test my project on but I'm getting the error below. I run

```
-gpu swiftshader
```

on commandline and I've tried devices with different android apis. I've also tried to do run another example project from Qt.io:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-textureinsgnode-example.html
but keep getting the same error. Any idea how to fix this?

`"org.qtproject.example.myproject" terminated.
Starting remote process.I art     : Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myproject/lib/x86/libQt5Network.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x12df0
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myproject/lib/x86/libQt5Network.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myproject/lib/x86/libQt5Qml.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x335d6
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myproject/lib/x86/libQt5Qml.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myproject/lib/x86/libQt5Gui.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x52dd3
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myproject/lib/x86/libQt5Gui.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myproject/lib/x86/libQt5Quick.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x46138
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myproject/lib/x86/libQt5Quick.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myproject/lib/x86/libQt5QuickParticles.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x52e5
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myproject/lib/x86/libQt5QuickParticles.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.myproject/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x92aa
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.myproject/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
I Qt      : qt start
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.myproject/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x16de
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.myproject/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myproject/lib/x86/libmyproject.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xb749
D         : (null):0 ((null)): QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
D OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa9aa170, tid 2503
D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae507330, tid 2520
I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.myproject/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x4bd
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.myproject/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa089cbb0, tid 2521
E EGL_emulation: tid 2521: eglCreateContext(960): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
W libmyproject.so: (null):0 ((null)): QEGLPlatformContext: Failed to create context: 3004
F libmyproject.so: (null):0 ((null)): Failed to create EGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBehavior(DoubleBuffer), swapInterval 1, profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2521 (QtThread)`

Comment: i've read somewhere that qt is not working on x86 android emulators, make sure you run it on armeabi emulator and selected armeabi build target

Comment: @V-master I've read that too but nowhere officailly and I believe I've seen it used by others.